# How to set correct color to lines?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on my first game in Unity.
I'm trying to draw lines on my game field.
Code:

```
    private void DrawLine(Vector3 start,  Vector3 stop, GameObject template)
{
    GameObject toInstiateGridLine = template;
    GameObject gridLineInstance = Instantiate(toInstiateGridLine, start, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    LineRenderer gridLineRenderer = gridLineInstance.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    gridLineRenderer.SetVertexCount(2);
    gridLineRenderer.SetWidth(0.01f, 0.01f);
    gridLineRenderer.SetColors(Color.black, Color.black);
    gridLineRenderer.SetPosition(0, start);
    gridLineRenderer.SetPosition(1, stop);
}
```

It works with one problem. I get pink lines instead of black that I expect.

[image: Game field]

Settings of LineRenderer component that has been created in runtime:
[image: LineRenderer settings]

Comment: problems with shader? What do you have in console?

Comment: @Valentin May be. But I'm absolutely new in GD and CG at all, so I have no idea where is the problem.

Comment: @Valentin
Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos 993.000000, 0.000000, 1000.000000) (Camera rect 0 0 993 657)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
Only this message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing material. Pink is the standard color when material is missing.

```
 LineRenderer gridLineRenderer = gridLineInstance.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
 Material mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Texture"));
 gridLineRenderer.material = mat;
```

Or, you can change material color directly. As I consider, calling directly will cause to create standard default material

```
gridLineRenderer.material.color = Color.white;
```