# Incorrect lines color showing in build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on my first game in Unity. I'm trying to draw lines on my game field.
I had a problem with line colors but now it is solved ([How to set correct color to lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424301/how-to-set-correct-color-to-lines))

But when I build my game and run it I see lins of pink color again.

Note that in Unity editor Game window everything is ok.

My code:

```
private void DrawLine(Vector3 start,  Vector3 stop, GameObject template)
{
    GameObject toInstiateGridLine = template;
    GameObject gridLineInstance = Instantiate(toInstiateGridLine, start, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    LineRenderer gridLineRenderer = gridLineInstance.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    gridLineRenderer.material.color = Color.black;
    gridLineRenderer.SetVertexCount(2);
    gridLineRenderer.SetWidth(0.01f, 0.01f);
    gridLineRenderer.SetColors(Color.black, Color.black);
    gridLineRenderer.SetPosition(0, start);
    gridLineRenderer.SetPosition(1, stop);
}
```

And screenshots.
Unity Game Window:
[image: Game]

Build window
[image: Build]

Comment: Have you checked the project graphics settings to make sure the shader (from the other question's answer) is included?

Comment: Did you create a new scene somewhere along the way that uses an old version of the script?  You may not be building the scene you intended.

Comment: @31eee384 I don't use  Material mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Texture"));
I use:
gridLineRenderer.material.color = Color.black;

Comment: @Draco18s I have only one scene

Comment: I think the shader that you're using might not be color-compatible for the specific platform that you're building to. Have you tried using a different shader?

Comment: @andeart No, I have not. I'm absolutely new in Unity and CG at all. What should I try?

Comment: @DmitriyDemidov In Unity, create a new Material (Assets > Create > Material). In the Shader drop-down (just under the name of the material in the Inspector panel), choose 'Unlit/Color'. Now drag-drop this material into the Materials/Element 0 in your prefab(template) object.

Comment: @andeart It helps! Many thanks!

Comment: @DmitriyDemidov I'm glad! Can you select my response below as the answer then please? This comment was basically an elaboration of experimenting with shaders :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
gridLineRenderer.material.SetColor ("_TintColor", Color.black);
```

instead of the current line you're using to change the material color.
Also try experimenting with different shaders.

`material.color = Color.black;` is basically shorthand for `material.SetColor ("_Color", Color.black)`. Some shaders use `_TintColor` rather than `_Color`.
I hope that helps!